# double sigma in complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

if $\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\cdots ,\beta_{100}$ are $100$ th roots of unity. The numerical value of $\displaystyle \mathop{\sum \sum}_{1\leq i\leq j\leq 100}\bigg(\beta_{i}\beta_{j}\bigg)^5$ is

what i try

assuming $x=(1)^{\frac{1}{100}},$ then $x^{100}-1=0$ has roots

$x=\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\cdots,\beta_{100}$

$\displaystyle x^{100}-1=(x-\beta_{1})(x-\beta_{2})\cdots \cdots (x-\beta_{100})$

how do i solve it help me please

Comment: This sum equals $1/2(\sum_{1\leq i, j \leq n}\beta_i^5 \beta_j^5 + \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n}\beta_i ^ 5)$. Then use the lemma that $\sum_{i \in S_1}\sum_{j\in S_2}f(i)g(j) = (\sum_{i \in S_1}f(i)) \cdot (\sum_{j \in S_2} f(j))$

Comment: @enedil dod not understand please explain me

Comment: What did you not understand?

Comment: @enedil first line

Comment: First you double count elements, without checking the condition that $i \leq j$, then add elements with indices $i, i$. Every element was doubly counted, so you just divide by two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We   obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq  i\leq     j\leq   100}}\color{blue}{\left(\beta_i\beta_j\right)^5}
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{100}\beta_j^5\sum_{i=1}^j\beta_i^5\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{100}\beta_1^{5j}\sum_{i=1}^j\left(\beta_1^5\right)^i\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{100}\beta_1^{5j}\frac{\beta_1^5-\left(\beta_1^5\right)^{j+1}}{1-\beta_1}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{\beta_1^5}{1-\beta_1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{100}\beta_1^{5j}-\sum_{j=1}^{100}\beta_1^{10j}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{\beta_1^5}{1-\beta_1}\left(\frac{\beta_1^5-\beta_1^{505}}{1-\beta_1^5}-\frac{\beta_1^{10}-\beta_1^{1010}}{1-\beta_1^{10}}\right)\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we rewrite the sum as double sum and factor out $\beta_j$.
- In (2) we use $\beta_j=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i j}{100}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{100}\right)^j=\beta_1^j$.
- In (3) we apply the *[finite geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (4) we factor out common terms and multiply out the sums.
- In (5) we again apply the *finite geometric series formula*. We  observe, since $\beta_1^{100}=1$ that $\beta_1^{505}=\beta_1^5$ and $\beta_1^{10}=\beta_1^{1010}$.

*Note:*

Since we have $\beta_1^{100}-1=(\beta_1-1)\left(1+\beta_1+\cdots+\beta_1^{99}\right)=0$ we  can deduce   the result      zero   already    from (4).